# inserting (+update) into multiple tables from query without losing reference

Tags: sql, oracle, reference, insert, cursor

I have this problem:

I have 3 tables - **RL_EST_SH** (ID,PARTY_ID), **PARTY**(ID), **COMM_PROP**(PARTY_ID,PERSID1,PERSID2) tables have other columns, but they are irrelevant.

**RL_EST_SH** is filled with IDs and other two are empty.

Than I have a query, select that returns me this result set (showing only first 10 rows):

```
REAL_ESTATE_SHARE_ID        PERSON_ID1                     PERSON_ID2                  
"4000"                        "17839"                       "17838"                       
"41572"                       "47306"                       "47305"                       
"41573"                       "47306"                       "47305"                       
"41765"                       "47712"                       "47711"                       
"41757"                       "47714"                       "47713"                       
"41803"                       "47716"                       "47715"                       
"41903"                       "47718"                       "47717"                       
"41907"                       "47720"                       "47719"                       
"41910"                       "47720"                       "47719"                       
"41713"                       "47720"                       "47719"
```

This query gives me two owners of REAL_ESTATE_SHARE_ID

Now here is my problem:

For every REAL_ESTATE_SHARE_ID in the result set of my query I need to create new Party (ID in table Party) using sequence P0_PARTY_S, assign this new ID to PARTY_ID column in RL_EST_SH for for IDs from query and create new record in COMM_PROP - record that keeps owners of REAL_ESTATE_SHARE_ID through PARTY_ID.

For better understanding here is simple draw:
[image]

I don't know how to do this without losing reference or how to do this at once. I was trying to user cursor, but I am not experienced enough to do so. I guess it is the right way but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is how far I am now...

```
declare 
REAL_ESTATE_SHARE_ID varchar2(19);
PERSON_ID1 VARCHAR2(19);
PERSON_ID2 VARCHAR2(19);
PERS_ID varchar2(19);
CURSOR C1 IS myquery;
BEGIN
OPEN C1;
LOOP
FETCH C1 INTO REAL_ESTATE_SHARE_ID, PERSON_ID1, PERSON_ID2;
EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
PERS_ID := P0_PARTY_S.nextval;
INSERT INTO P0_PARTY VALUES (PERS_ID,0,sysdate,':party.Party:party.Person:',sysdate,2,null,'SJM',93407656999);
INSERT INTO P5_COMMUNITY_PROPERTY VALUES (P5_COMMUNITY_PROPERTY_S.nextval,'Y',PERS_ID,PERSON_ID1, PERSON_ID2);
UPDATE BIZZTST.R0_RL_EST_SHARE set PARTY_ID = PERS_ID where BIZZTST.R0_RL_EST_SHARE.ID = REAL_ESTATE_SHARE_ID;
END LOOP;
CLOSE C1;
END;
```

This is causing `00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated" on this row:

```
INSERT INTO P5_COMMUNITY_PROPERTY VALUES (P5_COMMUNITY_PROPERTY_S.nextval,'Y',PERS_ID,PERSON_ID1, PERSON_ID2);
```

The third row has primary key constraint. Is it possible that my code is wrong and I am inserting same ID every time? 
How can I fix it?
Or my whole code is wrong?

Comment: Actually this works, the problem was with unique constraint on columns person_ID1 and person_id2. There can actually be non unique values. After removing unique constraint everything works fine :-)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the program however, you could have avoided creating the cursor by a FOR LOOP like this - 
`BEGIN
FOR prty_rec IN (SELECT * FROM MYQUERY) 
LOOP
INSERT ...
INSERT ...
UPDATE ...
END LOOP;
END;`
. To reference individual columns you would say `prty_rec.party_id`

Comment: I will definitely try it this way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to do an update on one table and insert on the other two, you'll have to use PL/SQL.

You don't even need a cursor if you are not familiar with it. Just create a `FOR LOOP` over the SELECT statement that gives you that resultset and do the 3 operations (1 update and 2 inserts). This way you can just create a variable to store the value of the sequence and use it in as many places as you like.

**If however all the tables were empty**, you could've done this in a single INSERT ALL statement which would look something like this -

```
INSERT ALL
INTO RL_EST_SH(ID, PARTY_ID) VALUES (REAL_ESTATE_SHARE_ID, PARTY_ID)
INTO PARTY(ID) VALUES (PARTY_ID)
INTO COMM_PROP (PARTY_ID,PERSID1,PERSID2) VALUES (PARTY_ID, PERSON_ID1, PERSON_ID2)
SELECT PARTY_ID_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL AS PARTY_ID, 
    REAL_ESTATE_SHARE_ID,
    PERSON_ID1,
    PERSON_ID2
FROM RESULTSET;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am not familiar much with PL/SQL..would you be so kind to show mi also the solution with for loop and cursor?

Comment: This is really basic pl/sql. Try to come up with a program and if you are stuck anywhere we'll help you out

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have written something...can you please check it and help me out?

Comment: The sollution of mine works, can you please review it? It it can be done better way or if there is anything wrong? Thank you :-)